# How to set by default tab in bottomnavigationbar using bottomnaivgationtab in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

If there is no internet connection and after loading in bottomnavigationtab they are not selected default tab but data should display of by-default tab.
[image]

In above image, there is 3rd default tab but after loading they select 1st tab..

Comment: I'm unsure I understand your issue. If it's about selecting a different default tab, use selectedIndex on bottom navigation component. If it's about tabs not loading properly, please share some sample code or preferably a Playground sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: 1st time when run the program they are showing proper selectedIndex tab, but when net is off that time i show some image and after net is on that loading and go to the dashboard but that time they are not show proper selectedIndex Tab...